# Problem setting selectedvalue for combobox in xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

Here is a snippet of my xaml:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="cbo1" Width="100" SelectedValue="200">
        <ComboBoxItem Name="n1">100</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Name="n2">200</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Why doesn't this work ? The '200' is not selected when I run it.
Ideally, I am trying to do SelectedValue="{Binding MyValue}".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selected value in this case is from type ComboBoxItem and not integer or string as you wished.

so what can you do against that? there exists a property for the combobox which defines which property of the selected object should be used as value and which as DisplayMember (the visualization)

in your case you have to set the SelectedValuePath to "Content". (The 200 are in your case the content of the ComboBoxItem)

example:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbo1" Width="100" SelectedValue="200" SelectedValuePath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem Name="n1">100</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Name="n2">200</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="cbo1" Width="100" >
       <ComboBoxItem Name="n1">100</ComboBoxItem>
       <ComboBoxItem Name="n2" IsSelected="True">200</ComboBoxItem>
 </ComboBox>
```

Comment: This does not help since the value to be selected is at runtime. I am actually trying to do SelectedValue={Binding MyValue} as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Sorry - was focus on getting the correct item selected.  fantasticfix's answer looks good.